# Stop video playback when turning TV off

Tags: pi-2, kodi, openelec

I have raspberri pi 2 with openelec installed. I use TV remote with HDMI-CEC. I've noticed when turning TV off from a remote while some video is playing back (IPTV channel, video form the local media server or online video) playback is not stopped and the device continues to consume Internet traffic. Is there any way to stop video playback when turning TV off?

Answer (score 1):

`tvservice` (call `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s` or `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -M` for continous monitoring) is the utility to handle HDMI status signals, such as HDMI cable unplugged.

With my setup - Pi2B and Samsung TV - there is a change of status for unplugging the HDMI cable and turning on the TV from stand-by. However there's no change detected during switching channels (e.g. from the HDMI channel the Pi is connected to something else) or turning off the TV set. Thus kodi cannot know to stop playback.

Rumor on the internet however has it that different brands/models of TV set might use HDMI-CEC differently. Check the behaviour using `tvservice`.